# Microservices in Cloud Run is not able to communicate

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have deployed spring boot microservices like eureka discovery server, API Gateway and other services.  I am calling all services through API Gateway through discovery server but in GCP Gateway is not able to communicate to other services, It keeps trying to connect after that getting connection timeout.  All the services are running in Cloud run.  Why Services in Cloud run is not able to communicate each other.

Comment: Too few info. Show how you invoke the other service and the API Gateway OpenAPI configuration

Comment: We have configured other services detail in Eureka/discovery server.  And all the calls invokes through Spring Boot API Gateway.

Comment: The following services (Spring Boot Applications) are deployed in the following  order in the GCP Cloud Run.
1. Discovery Service 
2. Cache Service Registered with Discovery Service
3. Gateway Service Registered with Discovery Service and also referred Cache Service
4. Auth Service Registered with Discovery Service and referred API Gateway.

Suppose we want to get Auth token (Anonymous or login) we make the call the Auth Service through Gateway.   


What I observed is Communication between microservices (Gateway to Auth or any other service) is not happening in GCP

Comment: How did you deploy the CLoud Run? In private mode? If so, you must add an ID token in the request header. You could configure your API Gateway to add it automatically.

Comment: Spring Boot API Gateway is not in Private Mode and I am able to invoke all the services from outside with no issues. Issue is within GCP.  Any firewall needs to be configured?

Comment: No, your gateway need to add an ID token in the header of the request when it forward the it to the correct Cloud Run service. You are in 0 trust environment, each call much be authenticated and authorized if you set Cloud Run private (no-allow-unauthenticated)

Comment: As I already said I set Cloud Run Public not private, why we need Token?

Comment: Did you set the traffic as "ingress internal"?

Comment: No, if you set traffic as ingress internal, then it will be considered as internal traffic only

Comment: I might not catch something in your configuration, I don't see any blocker. Maybe your Gateway  do something wrong. Does it changes some headers? Does it change the HOST header? Does it act as a proxy? a passthrough?

Comment: Actually issue is through load balancer. Call is not happening through this spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://AUTH-MICROSERVICE.  If I use actual uri instead of lb it is working.